# Amazon web service batch file upload using specific key

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to ask if there is any way to set a key for each uploaded file using the **TransferManager** (or any other class)? I am currently using the method **uploadFileList** for this and I noticed that I can define a callback for each file sent using the **ObjectMetadataProvider** interface, but I only have the **ObjectMetadata** at my disposal. I thought it would be possible to get the parent ObjectRequest and set the key value in there, but that does not seem to be possible.

*What I am trying to achieve:*

```
MultipleFileUpload fileUpload = tm.uploadFileList(bucketName, "", new File(directory), files, new ObjectMetadataProvider() {
            @Override
            public void provideObjectMetadata(File file, ObjectMetadata objectMetadata) {
                objectMetadata.getObjectRequest().setKey(myOwnKey);
            }
        });
```

I am most likely missing something obvious, but I spent some time looking for the answer and cannot find it anywhere. My problem is that if I supply some files for this method, it takes their absolute path (or something like that) as a key name and that is not acceptable for me. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I almost forgot about this post.
There was no elegant solution, so I had to resort to making my own transfer manager (**MultiUpload**) and check the list of each upload manually.
I can then set the key for each object upon creating the **Upload** object.

```
        List<Upload> uploads = new ArrayList();
        MultiUpload mu = new MultiUpload(uploads);

        for (File f : files) {
            // Check, if file, since only files can be uploaded.
            if (f.isFile()) {

                String key = ((!directory.isEmpty() && !directory.equals("/"))?directory+"/":"")+f.getName();

                ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();

                uploads.add(tm.upload(
                        new PutObjectRequest(bucketName,
                                key, f)
                                .withMetadata(metadata)));
            }
        }
```